# Java. how program loads data on startup and where to put it?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, load, bibliography

I am using NetBeans. I have this banal Bibliography program with 4 Classes: Book, Author, Bibliography, and Main.
I'm trying to understand how to load predefined data on startup, can anyone explain how **program  LOADS Book and Author and adds them to Bibliography Map on startup** and then display content of this Map.

**to simplify I am going to use just 1 map for one author and one book.**

Should I place all this code in **Main** Class:?

```
 Book book1 = new Book();
    Author auth1 = new Author();
    Map <Author, Book> bibMap= new HashMap<>;
    bibMap.put<book1, auth1>;
    "return Map;"
```

Or would it be better to implement this code in separate Class and call it from Main Class?

I know its all ultra simplified coding just trying to understand the basic idea.

**Can anyone recommend any good Java book which is rich with program examples?** The one I have shows only bits of code I need to see full working programs.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us to recommend you a book or tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading a [Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).  If you have the data in text format (e.g. books.txt or something) then you will probably want to create a FileReader, wrap it in a BufferedReader, and use that to read each line.  Then parse the lines as needed and put the data into your structures.